# Mysql query join issue

Tags: mysql, join

Im coming back to needing to use `SQL` again after not using it for years, and im running into an issue when trying to do something I guess would be considered a join. Heres what I got. I got a username which I need to reference back to a `user_id`, which is a simple

```
SELECT chat_user_id FROM chat_users WHERE chat_username = 'A1A1'
```

That works fine, but now I need to pass the `chat_user_id` to another query to get the chats related to that `user_id`. I know I have done this before, but havent done it in a long time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT whatever
FROM   chats c
INNER JOIN chat_users cu ON c.chat_user_id = cu.chat_user_id
WHERE  ch.chat_username = 'A1A1'
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. It should be cu.chat_username though, but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure specifically what you are asking without knowing the schemas for each.  From the vague description you gave, you *could* do a subquery.

Example:

```
SELECT somethingElse FROM someOtherTable WHERE chat_uer_id IN (SELECT chat_user_id FROM chat_users WHERE chat_username = 'A1A1');
```

While subqueries are not the most efficient thing in the world, that will work for what you are doing (If the subquery does **not** return multiple rows, then you can use "=" instead of "IN").

If you give me more information on the schema and what you are trying to do, I can help you with a more advanced JOIN.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but again, it seemed really inefficient

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT chat_username, chat.*
FROM chat_users
JOIN chat on chat_users.chat_user_id = chat.chat_user_id
WHERE chat_username = 'A1A1'
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can do something like this:

```
SELECT chat_username, chat.*
FROM chat_users
JOIN chat on chat_users.chat_user_id = chat.chat_user_id
WHERE chat_username = 'A1';
```